# different font-size between 2 pcs

Tags: html, css

in the div there are 3 spans. with css they get the font-size: 20pt; the Problem now is, my Computer Show me the right font-size, but on the other pc, with a higher Screen Definition, i don't see the right font-size. what's the Problem?

HTML:

```
<div id = "infoseite_balken">
    <div id = "ben">
        <img src = './images/logo-bw.png' width=80% height=100%>

    </div>
    <div id = "infoportkontakt" style = "border-color: red; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
        <?php

            echo "<span style = 'font-family: avril;' onClick = 'seiteBewegen(\"infoseite\",\"infoseite_disable\",\"1\",\"portfolio\",\"portfolio_enable\",\"1\",\"1500\"); starteOpacity(\"bild\",\"bildopacity\",\"10\",\"$countPortfolioview\");'>PORTFOLIO</span><br>";
        ?>
        <span style = "font-family: 'avril';">INFO</span><br>
        <span style = "font-family: 'avril'; " onClick = "seiteBewegen('infoseite','infoseite_disable','1','kontakt','kontakt_enable','0.5',1500);">KONTAKT</span><br>                  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#infoseite_balken {
    background-color: #3C3C3B; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 8%; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    min-height: 15%;
    height: auto;

}

#ben {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 30%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 1.5%;
}

#infoportkontakt {
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin-left: 50%;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 2%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 24pt;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: In place of pt, use px

Comment: it doesn't matter, i use em, px, pt always the same problem

Comment: Do  they have the same `zoom` level?

Comment: the have the same some level